# Why Background Video Is Not Showing

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to add a video background to my HTML document. I saw a tutorial on [Youtbue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoP2In1qJxc) on how to do that.. I copied everything and added to my document with the neccessary files such as the video but the problem is that it does not load my video. Here's the full code of my document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Video Background</title>



<style>

video#bgvid{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background: url(the_desert-wide2.png) no-repeat top center; /* replace **image link** with your own file*/
    background-size:cover;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<video id="bgvid" autoplay poster="img/bg.png"> <!-- replace **image link** with your own file -->

<source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogv" /><!-- replace **video link** with your own file -->

<source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" /><!-- replace **video link** with your own file -->

<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- replace **video link** with your own file -->

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically the video is not shown at all and instead the `bg.png` file appears. I opened the document on Opera, Firefox, Chrome and IE but nothing is shown :(

So do you know what should I do to load the video ? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this.  https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK
Hope this helps you.

Did you give full source address in src ?

```
<video autoplay  poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" loop>
  <!-- WCAG general accessibility recommendation is that media such as background video play through only once. Loop turned on for the purposes of illustration; if removed, the end of the video will fade in the same way created by pressing the "Pause" button  -->
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="polina">
<h1>Polina</h1>
<p>filmed by Alexander Wagner 2011
<p><a href="http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video">original article</a>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur porta dictum turpis, eu mollis justo gravida ac. Proin non eros blandit, rutrum est a, cursus quam. Nam ultricies, velit ac suscipit vehicula, turpis eros sollicitudin lacus, at convallis mauris magna non justo. Etiam et suscipit elit. Morbi eu ornare nulla, sit amet ornare est. Sed vehicula ipsum a mattis dapibus. Etiam volutpat vel enim at auctor.</p>
<p>Aenean pharetra convallis pellentesque. Vestibulum et metus lectus. Nunc consectetur, ipsum in viverra eleifend, erat erat ultricies felis, at ultricies mi massa eu ligula. Suspendisse in justo dapibus metus sollicitudin ultrices id sed nisl.</p>
<button>Pause</button>
</div>
```